# Can any HTTP headers force iOS to download video (rather than streaming it)

Tags: ios, ipad

Is it possible? My current headers are set to;

```
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Type: video/x-m4v
```

I tried setting a non-video content type (application/octet-stream) but it had no effect. Are there any headers  that will force an iOS device to download and save (rather than stream) a video file?

Comment: What are you trying to use to download it?

Comment: My question wasn't what are you downloading. It was: 'What do you want to download it with?' Saying you want to download with iOS doesn't tell us much. You could mean: Safari, another web browser, a web view within your app, a specific API in iOS such as NSURLConnection, or a 3rd party HTTP library. I suspect your question really is: "How can I get Mobile Safari to download a video to the user's video library?" And the short answer to that is: "You can't."

Comment: I don't really have any specific method that I wanted them to use. Ideally it would be Safari, but since that is apparently impossible I'd settle for anything that is reasonably easy.

Whatever method is the least complicated is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Assuming @GeorgeKendros wants to download to the iOS camera roll, I feel this is a relevant question (and one I have myself). Are there HTTP headers that make Safari on IOS download a video, instead of showing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you setting the `Content-Disposition` header because you expect Safari on iOS to act similar to desktop browsers when they come up against the same headers?

Mobile Safari doesn't act like this because iOS doesn't have the same file system paradigm as the desktop. The only way you'd be able to download the file to an iOS device would be saving the file within the sandboxed filesystem of your own app. To do this, you would manually download the file using the [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (and related) APIs.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out some way to have iOS download it instead of streaming it.

Comment: You're going to have to build your own iOS app, or use another app that can download arbitrary files.