# iOS Safari automatically save downloaded image

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari

I am working on a website where a png image is downloaded from a php script. By sending headers we force the image to download in most browsers.

In iOS the image opens in the browser tab taking the user away from the UI and forcing them to manually long click and choose "Save Image" to save the downloaded image in their Camera Roll.

The download script sends headers like these:

```
<?php
$fileName="image.png";
$filePath="/somepath/".$fileName;

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
header('Content-length: ' . filesize($filePath));

readfile($filePath);
exit;
```

I am wondering if there are any headers I can send that would cause mobile safari on iOS to send the image straight to the camera roll without extra user actions or if there is a JS api that would allow pushing of images into the Camera Roll.

I realise this may not be possible as ios apps to not access the filesystem directly the way other platforms allow and have looked at similar questions:

- [HTTP "Content-Disposition: attachment" and downloading files on iOS web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8620039)
- [Can any HTTP headers force iOS to download video (rather than streaming it)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16578453)

I am just hoping there might be something specific to images to cause safari to send an image to Photos or the Camera Roll rather than viewing it in Safari.

Comment: iOS doesn't work this way, as iOS respects user's consent before modifying their personal contents.

Comment: Convention over convenience, sounds like they were too lazy to implement.

Comment: @Kingpin2k It's very unlikely that this wasn't implemented because the iOS team was feeling "lazy". They purposely chose this behavior.

Comment: They purposely chose not to implement it because it would take them more time to implement it than to not implement it... sounds like laziness to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari doesn't access the filesystem except through user interaction, which means that the long press is the only way to get it into the Camera Roll. It's part of the sandboxing paradigm.

There isn't any equivalent of a "Downloads" directory.

Comment: At least on iOS8, I can't find a way to make even long press get it to the camera roll.

Comment: This is a real bummer. At least, iOS could show a dialoge "save the file ..?" [yes] [no]  that would also require user interaction and thus satisfy the sandbox paradigm. ...i hate apple... :-(